# 8 puzzle admissible heuristic where tiles are in correct position

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, heuristics

For the 8 puzzle problem, it has been proved that if h(n) = number of tiles on wrong place. h(n) is an admissible heuristic as every tile which is in wrong place must be moved out at least once.

But if h(n) = number of tiles on correct place. h(n) is  not an admissible heuristic. Can anybody please explain.

Comment: Try to use the definition of admissible heuristic.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: To show that something is not an admissible heuristic, you need to show that it doesn’t satisfy the definition.

Comment: yeah, by definition, a heuristic to be admissible to the search problem, the estimated cost must always be lower than or equal to the actual cost of reaching the goal state. So if 7 tiles is in correct place we got h(n) =7 and 1 is in wrong place. We can move this tile by 1 move. In that case, the actual cost  is less than h(n). Then it should be admissible heuristic, isn't it.

Comment: An admissible heuristic is one that lower bounds the cost of all possible solutions. If you have to move only 1 tile but your heuristic says 7 tiles, then it’s not admissible.